# Unlimited levels in dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a generated unordered list with list inside which I want to make into a dropdown menu.

The problem is that I don't know how many levels there will be, and I only want to show one level at a time.

So far I got this:

---

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">link1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">link2.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                       <a href="#">link2.1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav ul {
}
.nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
}
.nav li:hover ul { 
    display: block; 
}
```

---

This code however show all the sub-ul's when hover at top. And what I want is only to show the next level, and have sub-levels under that one hidden. And so on. But still show levels above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PxxjN/)***

```
.nav ul {
}
.nav li ul {
    display: none;
}
.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
}
.nav li:hover>ul { //change here
    display: block; 
}
```

Instead of showing all `ul` children of `hover`, show only direct children.